# Powershell: Can I use an existing enum for my own function's parameters?

Tags: powershell, parameters, enums

I want to re-use an already-existing enum for my own functions. I want the enum from `Test-Path -PathType`. As in, I want my own function that has a parameter `PathType` that accepts `Any`, `Leaf`, or `Container`.

Can this be done without re-defining the enum? How do I determine what the enum itself is actually called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the [TestPathType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.powershell.commands.testpathtype%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) enum. You should be able to accept it as a formal argument, eg:

```
function Do-Something([Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathType] $pathType) {
  ...
}
```

By the way, Powershell will tell you the type of an argument in the error message when you provide an invalid value, eg:

```
Test-Path -PathType Banana
```

yields:

```
Test-Path : Cannot bind parameter 'PathType'. Cannot convert value "Banana" to type
"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.TestPathType". Error: "Unable to match the identifier name Banana to a valid enumerator
name.  Specify one of the following enumerator names and try again: Any, Container, Leaf"
At line:1 char:21
```

But if you want to be more proactive about looking at command metadata, you can inspect it directly, eg:

```
(Get-Command Test-Path).Parameters.PathType.ParameterType
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not see a way to "Get at" the individual parameters until you showed me (Get-Command Test-Path).Parameters

Comment: It appears that the TestPathType enum went away in PowerShell 6.